# How to use LINQ with dynamic collections

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to  convert `dynamic` object to `IEnumerable` Type to filter collection with property.

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

I need to access something like this

```
var a = data.Where(p => p.verified == true)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: you could use [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

So long as `data` is an `IEnumerable` of some kind, you can use:

```
var a = ((IEnumerable) data).Cast<dynamic>()
                            .Where(p => p.verified);
```

The `Cast<dynamic>()` is to end up with an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` so that the type of the parameter to the lambda expression is also `dynamic`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm interested to see what is your idea about the Yasser's answer. Is there any significant difference?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: Yes - mine will work even if it's a sequence of a value type; Yasser's won't. I've added a comment.

Answer (score 56):

Try casting to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

```
((IEnumerable<dynamic>)data).Where(d => d.Id == 1);
```

This approach is 4x faster than other approachs.

good luck

Comment: Is there any difference between your solution and the solution provided by @Jon Skeet

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Cast method of Enumerable class in .NET will cast every member of passed IEnumerable (data in this case) to something (dynamic in this case), so if your data has 1000 items, that code will perform 1000 casts, but my code has only one cast.

Comment: The downside is that this doesn't work for an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a value type, e.g. a `List<int>`. Sometimes that may be relevant, other times it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to, the ideal solution is to specify the type when deserializing, so to avoid having to cast later. This is a lot cleaner than the approaches suggested above.

So if you have -

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

Then simply change this to -

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, replace jsonString with response.Content and use nested loops if required based on your response content.

In the below code JValue.Parse will return JToken which is IEnumerable

```
        string jsonString = "[{\"Question\":{\"QuestionId\":49,\"QuestionText\":\"Whats your name?\",\"Answer\":\"xyz\"}},{\"Question\":{\"QuestionId\":51,\"QuestionText\":\"Are you smart?\",\"Answer\":\"Yes\"}}]";
        dynamic myObject = JValue.Parse(jsonString);
        foreach (dynamic questions in myObject)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(questions.Question.QuestionId + "." + questions.Question.QuestionText.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Ans. " +questions.Question.Answer);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Where do you "convert dynamic object to IEnumerable" as the question states?

Comment: This solution is an alternative way without converting dynamic object to IEnumerable. JValue.Parse will return JToken which is IEnumerable