# dynamic object in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Is it possible to access to the a dynamic object with an index ?

here is my code :

```
 var Participants = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(obj.ToString()).AsQueryable();  


var query = from p in Participants
               where p[2] == "Yes"  //  I need to access to the 2nd column
               select
```

the column name is dynamic, but i have to test with the 2nd one . Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734996/how-to-use-linq-with-dynamic-collections

Comment: but the column name is changing also , did u get my point ?

Comment: plz help i couldnt make it work

Comment: It would be useful to supply a sample of your JSON document so people may fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the type you are casting to dynamic do not implement an indexer you cannot access the indexer by casting it to dynamic and use the `[]` syntax

If you have access to the source code of the class you should implement the indexer like this:

```
public int this[ int i ]
{
    get
    {
        //return the column you are interested in
    }
}
```

Other option, if the class expose a property that represents the columns you can access them dynamically:

```
p.Columns[2] == "yes"
```