# Create Lists from a List based on a distinct value

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a result set which starts with the following 4 columns. They come back from a stored procedure call.

[image]

What that result has is two different IDs.

What I need to do is `foreach` through each list and get the distinct IDs of the result set (I can't use LINQ right now, as it's actually a dynamic type), and add the rows to a new `List<>`.

So, in the case of this example, I'll end up with two `List<>`s. One, for Id 119948, with 4 rows, and one for Id 14765 with 3 rows.

Is the only way to accomplish this to first foreach through the list and get the distinct ids, then foreach the distinct list, and then foreach through the list again and add them to a List<>?

Comment: Yes. That is the easiest way using inbuilt distinct method, or else you have to frame your own logic to foreach through the entire list add each element it to a separate list(which will be distinct list) by checking if the element is already present in the list, and 2 separate lists for each ids. Instead I would suggest you to go with dictionary in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. So I go through the whole list fiirst, and get all the distinct ids. (So I have a List<int> with two Ids. I then iterate through that list, and then foreach through the main list where id = the current id. Seems a bit sketchy, but it works.

Comment: That is the straight forward way though

Comment: Hey Craig, why dont you use Linq with GroupBy Distinct, maybe you will not need two foreach loops..

Comment: With LINQ unavailable you pretty much need to roll your own [`Enumerable.GroupBy` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) or [`Enumerable.ToLookup` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx), either of which would only need to enumerate the sequence once.  Like @SethuBala said, enumerate each row, adding it to a `Dictionary` keyed on its `Id` (specifically, a `Dictionary<int, List<Row>>`).

Comment: Have you tried filtering/grouping the data in the SQL query that call the stored procedure?

Comment: @Craig how are you executing your stored procedure call? For example, are you executing through something like a [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) method call, which would then return a `SqlDataReader` object?

Comment: Do a `GroupBy` on linq rather than manually with a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding**

> I can't use LINQ right now, as it's actually a dynamic type

[Linq still works with dynamic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734996/how-to-use-linq-with-dynamic-collections).

**Regarding**

> If the only way to first foreach through the list and get the distinct
>   ids, and then foreach distinct, foreach through the list again and add
>   them to a List<>?

**No**, assuming I understood the problem you are having with dynamic types, you can do one of the following with Linq:

If the output is required to be a list of lists, and the way the stored procedure in the question is being executed results in a [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx), you could do the following with [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) (substituting your own values for my example values, including the casting of types from the dataRecord):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<YourType>> yourListOfLists;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(someStoreProcedureName, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        yourListOfLists = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                                 .ToList()
                                 .Select(dataRecord =>
                                 new YourType()
                                 {
                                     VersionNumber = dataRecord.GetInt32(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("VersionNumber")),
                                     Id = dataRecord.GetInt32(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                                     FromType = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("FromType")),
                                     FromStatusId = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("FromStatusId"))
                                 })
                                 .GroupBy(youObject => youObject.Id)
                                 .Select(group => group.ToList())
                                 .ToList();
    }
}
```

If what you really wanted was two distinct lists based off of some Id:

```
IEnumerable<YourType> listOfId1;
IEnumerable<YourType> listOfId2;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(someStoreProcedureName, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var combinedList = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                                 .ToList()
                                 .Select(dataRecord =>
                                 new YourType()
                                 {
                                     VersionNumber = dataRecord.GetInt32(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("VersionNumber")),
                                     Id = dataRecord.GetInt32(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                                     FromType = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("FromType")),
                                     FromStatusId = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("FromStatusId"))
                                 });

        listOfId1 = combinedList.Where(item => item.Id == 111111).ToList();
        listOfId2 = combinedList.Where(item => item.Id == 222222).ToList();
    }
}
```

Please note that there are most likely better ways to execute stored procedures than what was shown in this example.

Answer (score 1):

> If the only way to first foreach through the list and get the distinct ids, and then foreach distinct, foreach through the list again and add them to a List<>?

Imagine sorting crayons into bins by color (and bins are free to make).  Would you first go through all of the crayons, make a list of what colors you have, and then go back and separate them?  No, you'd separate them as you go, adding more bins as necessary.

So no, you don't have to make two passes over the collection.  You just find the "key" value for each item, see if a "bucket" has already been created.  If so, add it to that bucket. If not, add a new bucket to the output collection and add the item to that bucket.  That's essentially what `GroupBy` does.