# Compare first child with linq dynamic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic

I'm pretty new with [linq dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) and i need to translate a simple linq query

Supossing i have this classes

```
public class Parent
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Child> Childrens {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
   public decimal exampleData {get;set;}
   public decimal moreData {get;set;}
}
```

I need to show in a table, the parent properties and the first child property (sorted desc), I have no problem doing this, the issue is that I also need to filter it (only the first result after ordering it).

The thing is, i need to filter `Parent` list not filtering childrens, just comparing the first one

With normal linq i can do something like this for example

```
List<Parent> result =  db.Parent.Where(c => c.Childrens.OrderBy(c => c.exampleData).FirstOrDefault().moreData > 300).ToList()
```

Is it possible with linq dynamics? or another library? how can i do this

Comment: If you need to order the parent list then what is it for `c.Childrens.OrderBy(c => c.exampleData)` ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Its because i need filter the parent with the first result after order the collection asc (as if it were a parent property) do u understand me?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18735049/2477582

Comment: @Nicolas no isn't, basically my problem is that i need to compare the first child property like it was a parent property

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal ok I am starting to understand what you mean, but just to get it clear: your line in your question (after applying all the conditions) returns a list of children, but you need a list of their respective parents? //Edit: or different question: what is wrong with the line you wrote in your question?

Comment: @Nicolas nothing is wrong, it actually work, the thing is that `moreData` can be another property, so i need to translate it to Linq Dynamics and i cant find the replacement of `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Why don't you use `FirstOrDefault()` then? Not supported by the Dynamic LINQ? What exact Dynamic LINQ package are you using (because there are several builds AFAIK), can you provide a link?

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for response I'm using [System.Linq.Dynamic (1.0.7)](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic), when i try to use `FirstOrDefault()` it throws and i cant found anything to replace it

Comment: Try this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicLinq - I've tested it (the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` part) on EF Core and it supports `FirstOrDefault`. e.g. `Where("Childrens.OrderBy(exampleData).FirstOrDefault().moreData > 300")` should work.

Comment: @IvanStoev it works, thanks so much! answer the question so i mark it as correct please

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several Dynamic LINQ packages, all with different LINQ methods support.

I would suggest using [EntityFramework.DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicLinq).

First because it's listed in [EF Core extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) (the [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) package which contains the shared functionality).

Second and more importantly, because it supports `FisrtOrDefault` method that you need :)

So the following works with that package:

```
.Where("Childrens.OrderBy(exampleData).FirstOrDefault().moreData > 300")
```